# Print bibliography in the order as entered in the bib file without sorting

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

I am using natbib agsm style.
I would like to have bibliographies printed as entered in the bib file (without sorting) which is divided as Article, Books etc. How should I modify the code?

the code is as follows

```
\documentclass[twosided,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\renewcommand\bibname{}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
\bibliography{publications}
\end{document}
```

and this is my bib file

```
@article{xya,
    title={},
    author={},
    journal={},
    volume={86},
    number={SI},
    pages={184--192},
    year={2019b},
    publisher={}
}

@book{,
    title={},
    author={},
    journal={},
    volume={61},
    number={2},
    pages={13--21},
    year={2019a},
    publisher={}
}
and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Rainer in https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26766

> A \nocite{*} before the first \cite command in combination with one of
> the unsrt styles might do what you want.

As you are using the `agsm` bibliography style, you need to make a copy of the `agsm.bst` file, create your own `myagsm.bst`, and comment the `SORT` commands in it. Then just change to your new defined `myagsm` style.

```
\bibliographystyle{myagsm}
```